# JDBC Can't connect to my DB from a separate class. Class DB creates the connection

Tags: java, sql-server, database, jdbc, prepared-statement

I have been trying to have my JDBC database connection be performed from its own separate class (DB.java) so that whenever I wanted to create a new connection from any of my other multiple classes (eg. CusTab.java) I can just create an instance of DB. After running my first test, which consisted on printing table contents to console I found myself with an error:

```
Something wrong with prepared statement test
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The connection is closed.
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:190)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.checkClosed(SQLServerConnection.java:388)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.prepareStatement(SQLServerConnection.java:2166)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.prepareStatement(SQLServerConnection.java:1853)
at marsPackage.CusTab.<init>(CusTab.java:129)
```

Here is my DB.java class, the one that starts the connection to my database KIS_DB it uses windows authentication and for now my GUI connects locally with the DB.

```
package marsPackage;

import java.sql.*;

public class DB {

private Connection dbConn = null;

public Connection getConnection(){
    //This condition will check if the connection is not already open
    if (null == dbConn){
        //Setup a connection to the database
        String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://CoT-CIS3365-1\\MSSQLSERVER;databaseName=KIS_DB;integratedSecurity=true"; 
        try {
            Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            System.err.println("Class.forName thing is not working here");
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        try{
            dbConn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);

            PreparedStatement useStmt;
            try{
                useStmt = dbConn.prepareStatement("USE KIS_DB");
                useStmt.executeUpdate();
            }
            catch(SQLException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        catch(SQLException e){
            System.err.println("There was a problem connecting to the Database");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally{
            if (dbConn != null)
                try{dbConn.close();} catch(SQLException e){e.printStackTrace();}
        }
    }
    return dbConn;
}
}
```

Here is my test to print a simple result set into console, this comes from the CusTab.java class, since the code in this class is huge I will just enter the snippet where I try to use my DB.

```
            DB db = new DB();
        try {
            String sql = "SELECT * FROM PROJECT_STATUS;";
            PreparedStatement Stmt = db.getConnection().prepareStatement(sql);
            ResultSet rs = Stmt.executeQuery();
        while(rs.next()){
                System.out.println("PRO_STATUS_ID: "+rs.getString(1));
                System.out.println("PRO_STATUS_NAME: "+rs.getString(2));    
        }
        } catch (SQLException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            System.err.println("Something wrong with prepared statement test");
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I thank you in advance for your time.

**Update:** With @ppuskar advice I was able to fix this issue. I removed the Finally block in the DB class because it closed my connection prematurely. Then I added a close() method to DB.java, this method closes the connection when used.

```
/*
        finally{
            if (dbConn != null)
                try{dbConn.close();} catch(SQLException e){e.printStackTrace();}
        }*/
    }
    return dbConn;
}

public void close(){
    try {
        dbConn.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        System.err.println("Could not close the connection");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at your getConnection() API, you are closing the connection in the finally block. BTW i do not understand why you are executing a   `useStmt.executeUpdate();` in getConnection()

Comment: I was reusing a solution found in here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8479924/trying-to-query-database-using-preparedstatement-resultset-is-coming-back-close I thought the reason he closed the connection within the finally block was so that the connection will close after it was done being used. I have however removed that finally block and that useStmt.executeUpdate(); line of code which, you are right, makes no sense. Instead of using that finally block I created a new method that closes the connection when called. I will update my question with my changes which fixed the issue.